# How to re-render react component depends on a file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a file that stores an array of objects. I have a component that fetches data from this file then render the list. The file could be updated somewhere else, I need the component to be updated if the file is modified. I have following code example

```
const header = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  
  // fetch 
  useEffect(() => {
    const loadList = async () => {
      const tempList = await getList("/getlist"); // get call to fetch data from file
      setList(tempList);
    };
    loadList ();
  }, [list]);

  // function to render content
  const renderList = () => {
    return list.map(obj => (
      <div key={obj.name}>
        {obj.name}
      </div>
    ));
  };
  
  return (
    <div>{renderList()}</div>
  )
}

// get call
router.get('/getlist', 
  asyncWrapper(async (req, res) => {
    const result = await getList();
    res.status(200).json(result).end();
  })
);

const getList= async () => {
  const list = JSON.parse(await fs.readFile(listPath));
  return list;
}
```

Code has been simplified. If I remove the list from useEffect, then it will only render once and will never update unless I refresh the page. If I include list there, loadList() will get called constantly, and component will get re-rendered again and again. This is not the behavior I want. I am just wondering without making header component async component, how do I only re-render this component when the file is changed?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you use Class Components?

Comment: No, I need to use funtional component.

Comment: What happens if you give an empty dependency array and ignoring the errors, does it work?

Comment: No, I tried that. It does not work. If it's empty, it will render the first time, but will never update the component with new list if the file is changed.

Comment: Do you mean that the file gets modified from the server-side and you need to detect a change?

Comment: Yes. file is on the server side. And I want to detect the change and trigger the re-render of this component with updated list from the file.

Comment: Unless the other service/endpoint where the file resides has some notification mechanism then you can't simply keep downloading the file, your _dependency_ is not local! Simplest option: use `setInterval()` to do it every now and then. Then simply [deep] compare the two arrays to know if they're different (and in that case you can call `setList()`. Then check if the component has been unmounted before calling `setList()` because `fetch()` is async. Then you may consider to use a GET instead of a POST (if possible) to let the browser cache the file when unchanged (or set the appropriate params)

Comment: With some co-operation from the server you might do better.

Comment: Yes, the call is a get instead of a post. I guess I need to figure out the dependency.

Comment: This has pretty much nothing to do with react, you need to find a way to communicate with the target server. If you have controll over it, one solution other than the one  @Adriano Repetti offered, is to use `websockets` to keep the connection alive between client-server and have the server listening on changes to that file and when it detects a change, it will simply message you back. Then you can just change the state `setList`.

Comment: I second what @contour said, you do not need to "figure out the dependency" because you do not have one. Is the server available for changes? Setup _something_, websocket or even just long polling (!). If not then use `useEffect()` with `[]` dependency to initialize (and cleanup...) a timer with `setInterval()`. As simple as that!

Comment: Ok. I see your point now. Thank you.

Comment: can you add the `getList` functions?

Comment: The suggestions here are great. I'll just add that you ahouls also consider using `useMemo()` (along with the `setInterval()` ).

Comment: Get call is added. Yes, setInterval was considered, but it will cause some performance issue even with useMemo.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches you can take to this:

## Polling

Request the URL on an interval, and clear it when the component is unmounted.

Replace `loadList ()` with:

```
const interval = setInterval(loadList, 60000); // Adjust interval as desired
return () => clearInterval(interval)
```

Make sure the cache control headers set in the response to `/getlist` don't stop the browser from noticing updates.

## Server push

Rip out your current code to get the data and replace it with something using websockets, possibly via Socket.IO. (There are plenty of tutorials for using Socket.io with React that can be found with Google, but its rather too involved to be part of a SO answer).